# How to make image weight and height fill screen in Swift Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, image, slider, size

I found a code to make slide in swift, but cant find, h**ow to make the IMAGE fill the whole screen.**
Could you help?

here is the screenshot of slider, and you will see the anchors I placed on it to show you, the whole screen.

[image]

**and here is the code of it;**

```
import UIKit
class OnboardingController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    let backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 241.0/255.0, green: 196.0/255.0, blue: 15.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    let slides = [
        [ "image": "book4page1.png"],
        [ "image": "book4page2.png"],
        [ "image": "book4page3.png"],
    ]
    let screen: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    var scroll: UIScrollView?
    var dots: UIPageControl?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
        scroll = UIScrollView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: screen.width, height: screen.height * 0.9))
        scroll?.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        scroll?.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        scroll?.pagingEnabled = true
        view.addSubview(scroll!)
        if (slides.count > 1) {
            dots = UIPageControl(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: screen.height * 0.875, width: screen.width, height: screen.height * 0.05))
            dots?.numberOfPages = slides.count
            view.addSubview(dots!)
        }
        for var i = 0; i < slides.count; ++i {
            if let image = UIImage(named: slides[i]["image"]!) {
                let imageView: UIImageView = UIImageView(frame: getFrame(image.size.width, iH: image.size.height, slide: i, offset: screen.height * 0.15))
                imageView.image = image
                scroll?.addSubview(imageView)
            }
            if let text = slides[i]["text"] {
                let textView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: screen.width * 0.05 + CGFloat(i) * screen.width, y: screen.height * 0.745, width: screen.width * 0.9, height: 100.0))
                textView.text = text
                textView.editable = false
                textView.selectable = false
                textView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
                textView.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(20, weight: 0)
                textView.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
                textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
                scroll?.addSubview(textView)
            }
        }
        scroll?.contentSize = CGSizeMake(CGFloat(Int(screen.width) *  slides.count), screen.height * 0.5)
        scroll?.delegate = self
        dots?.addTarget(self, action: Selector("swipe:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
        let closeButton = UIButton()
        closeButton.frame = CGRect(x: screen.width - 70, y: 20, width: 60, height: 60)
        closeButton.setTitle("Skip", forState: .Normal)
        closeButton.setTitleColor(UIColor(red: 0.0/255.0, green: 0.0/255.0, blue: 0.0/255.0, alpha: 0.5), forState: .Normal)
        closeButton.titleLabel!.font =  UIFont.systemFontOfSize(16)
        closeButton.addTarget(self, action: "pressed:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(closeButton)
    }
    func pressed(sender: UIButton!) {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true) { () -> Void in
        }
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
    func getFrame (iW: CGFloat, iH: CGFloat, slide: Int, offset: CGFloat) -> CGRect {
        let mH: CGFloat = screen.height * 0.50
        let mW: CGFloat = screen.width
        var h: CGFloat
        var w: CGFloat
        let r = iW / iH
        if (r <= 1) {
            h = min(mH, iH)
            w = h * r
        } else {
            w = min(mW, iW)
            h = w / r
        }
        return CGRectMake(
            max(0, (mW - w) / 2) + CGFloat(slide) * screen.width,
            max(0, (mH - h) / 2) + offset,
            w,
            h
        )
    }
    func swipe(sender: AnyObject) -> () {
        if let scrollView = scroll {
            let x = CGFloat(dots!.currentPage) * scrollView.frame.size.width
            scroll?.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(x, 0), animated: true)
        }
    }
    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) -> () {
        let pageNumber = round(scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width)
        dots!.currentPage = Int(pageNumber)
    }
    override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
        return UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent
    }
}
```

Comment: well given the aspect ration of the image, the image does not fit into the view in portrait mode, without "cropping" the image. So what do you want? Do you want a UIImageView inside a UIScrollView so that you can pan around in the image? Or do you want to crop the image?

Comment: Have you tried changing the content mode for your image view? like this: `imageView.contentMode = .ScaleToFill`

Answer (score 1):

On your `imageView` set `imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit`

Comment: my code is a bit different.. could you check it?
I see some codes at the bottom of file. Maybe for that reason, it s not allowed to use .ScaleAspectFit

Comment: @ali, you have your imageView just add the above code to it. `let imageView: UIImageView = UIImageView(frame: getFrame(image.size.width, iH: image.size.height, slide: i, offset: screen.height * 0.15))
                imageView.image = image
                imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
                scroll?.addSubview(imageView` - like this (this is your code snippet that I have added the contentMode to).

Comment: no. I cant solve. Because your code isnt working. I didnt use storyboard to create UIImageView, but created it with code.
You can check the whole code here; https://github.com/lucasjgordon/Onboarding

Comment: hi... you checked? @Rashwan L

Comment: @ali, try this `let imageView: UIImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height))`

Comment: works for the first pic of slide, but not working for the other images.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you want it to scale you should modify the [contentMode](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/contentMode)

of the UIImageView's.

Answer (score 0):

In Objective-C you would do this (it'll be something similar in Swift):

```
UIImageView * iv = [UIImageView new];
iv.frame = scrollView.bounds;
iv.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
iv.clipsToBounds = true;
iv.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.jpg"];
[scrollView addSubview:iv];
```

The contentMode is the line you're looking for.